# Find $\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-t}{t(1-0.5t)}}dt$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find $\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-t}{t(1-0.5t)}}dt$.
I think that we can not use integration by parts and partial fractions. Is it possible to use change of variable and properties of definite integral? Or any other method? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is a tricky one. It can be turned into an elliptic integral or... check my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{t(1-t/2)}}\,dt = 2\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-u^2}{2-u^2}}\,du=2\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1-2v^2}{1-v^2}}\,dv $$

$$ I = 2\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}\,d\theta = \sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos\varphi\right)^{1/2}\,d\varphi = \frac{4\pi\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}$$

by Euler's Beta function and the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: More concisely, $t=1-\cos\varphi$.

Comment: Thanks @J.G.. This change of variable shortens the problem more.